# Live TV Stream to Android

Tags: android, html, video, ffmpeg

I am new user on stackoverflow.
I wrote you today to get answer and solution to my problem.
I have input stream come from vlc. I need that all android connected to my network can watch stream in live in the same time like an online channel tv.
I saw for this channel

Code: Select all
    www.canal2international.net/live.php

there is a same ts file is generated for each 45 second.

I need to do the same but with a mp4 file that I insered on html5 video tag.
for that I tried to convert my input stream with this cmd on ffmpeg

Code: Select all
    ffmpeg -i 192.168.1.10:8620 -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -c:a aac -ar 44100 -ac 2 -b:a 128k -f segment -segment_time 45 -segment_format_options movflags=+faststart -segment_list D:\live\play.m3u8 -segment_list_size 2 D:\live\watch%03d.mp4

I'm not satisfied. I can't insert m3u8 file in html5 video tag because android don't read it and his content.

I tried another code that I can say little similar that the result of this page

Code: Select all
    www.canal2international.net/live.php

Code: Select all
    ffmpeg -i 192.168.1.10:8620 -hls_flags single_file D:\live\play.m3u8

It generated two files, a ts and a m3u8.
I know that html5 video tag can read ts file. Maybe there is a solution somewhere.

The second way I don't like in this code is ts file don't read in real time. When I read file it begin from the first encoding.

All android connected to my network must watch in real time!

I don't know how to solve my problem that's why I write in thie forum.

Thank you in advance for all your help!

Comment: ***"I write in this forum"*** SO isn't a forum.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Right now I understand.
Can you help me please?

Thank you again!

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)